# Como llamar a una función de python desde javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

Eso pues, tengo este archivo .js:

```
function loginData (formData) {
    //llamar a funcion verificar de clase validate
}



var onLogin = (event) => {
    const user = document.getElementById('user').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('user' , user);
    formData.append('password', password);
    loginData(formData);
}

var main = () => {

    document.querySelector('#but-ingresar')
        .addEventListener('click', onLogin);
}

window.addEventListener('load', main);
```

Básicamente saca los datos de un formulario: usuario y contraseña, y lo que quiero hacer es mandarlos a una función python de una clase:

```
class validate():
    def verificar(self, request):
        user = request.user #Aca deberia de sacar el usuario del javascript
        password = request.password #Aca deberia de sacar la contraseña del javascript
        ...
```

La cuestion es que he probado con un `fetch` en el javascript en la función loginData y nada.

Comment: Aquí hay dos temas diferentes. Primero tienes que hacer que tu API en Python funcione y probarla de forma independiente y luego consumirla con JS.

Comment: solo quiero que se pueda ejecutar el codigo python cuando se le llame desde el javascript, luego arreglo el python

Comment: Para ello debes exponer un *endpoint* en tu API hecha en Python. Es lo que te acaban de comentar más arriba, pero por lo visto no lo has entendido. No puedes ejecutar código Python en el navegador, el código Python se ejecutará en el servidor.

Comment: tipo un ````fetch```` ?

Comment: Recuerda que tu explorador Web tiene un motor de Javascript , no interpreta Python. Si lo que tienes ahí es una página vas a tener que pasarla JS para poder utilizarla en un explorador web... Al menos para los exploradores web habituales.

Comment: lo que pasa es que tengo que hacer las operaciones en python y luego recien me redirecciona a otra pagina, eso se hace con un ````return redirect("ejemplo.com/ejemplo")````